# UWP WebView third party Alternatives

Tags: .net, winforms, uwp, winjs, c++-winrt

I have an application built on UWP using WinJS and WinRT to interact with different devices attached, I am opening a webview pointing to an existing web application built on angular js.

Problem is I am facing increase in memory and then after some time it is crashing the UWP application.

For testing, I created an empty UWP application with no WinJS and WinRT just opened the same web site in a webview and played with it. I observed the same thing after some time application got crashed.

Then I created a Win Forms application, added Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView  and used web view in that and pointed it to the same link and I observed there was no crash in application even memory went very high (almost 2gb).

Do we have any third party webview available or if someone has faced same issues like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 3rd party web view on UWP by definition. While you can access some desktop APIs by using the exe files in the same package, you can't mix UWP with the desktop controls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have managed to resolve the issue of application crashing instead of rearchiture or going to any other browser :-)